# Best way of tracking changes code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an Asp.NET form. On page load, I am populating text boxes and drop down lists.

When the user clicks on the edit button, I want to know if the user changed the values or selected a new value **but then** re-selected the old value and didn't actually change anything.

I can think of two methods:

- Create hidden labels for each input and then track in code behind.
- Use session state or re-query the source where I uploaded the data from in the first place.

Do you know any better way?

Comment: When do you want to know? On page in javascript while they are manipulating the form? After post back?

Comment: @xdumaine it going to be code behind when Edit button will be clicked :)

Comment: Then you'll have to re-query the data source. If you use hidden inputs, you'll be posting twice as much data as necessary, and it can't be trusted anyway (since the user could use browser tools to manipulate hidden inputs, or fake the entire POST).

Comment: When page loads, you will have to fill up hidden fields along with actual inputs and than compare them when user clicks edit button.

Comment: Why not use Viewstate..?

Answer (score -2):

you can use a [**stringbuilder**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)

At page load you can put all values in stringbuilder now create a another stringbuilder in that put changes values or values after button editing of records completed

After that you can compare two string

or you can store those strings in database for future reference

Comment: Please don't do this.

Comment: Seconded. You think this is a good idea please please please - work for the competition before ending up with a job outside IT. Horrific.